# Using jpype to getInstance a singleton object in a jar file

Tags: java, python, jpype

I'm facing some problems to getInstance from a singleton object because jpype needs a default constructor to instantiate classes, but singletons don't have a default constructor or just keep it private to force get instance by getInstance method. When I try to get instance, I see this error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/myuser/PycharmProjects/PythonTests/JavaTests.py", line 21, in <module>
        service = jpype.JClass("com.classpackage.Service")
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jclass.py", line 54, in JClass
        raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)
    jpype._jexception.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class com.classpackage.Service not found
```

the code it this below

```
import jpype

jpype.startJVM("/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so",
               "-Djava.class.path=Service.jar")

jpype.java.lang.System.out.println("Hello!!!")

MODEL_PACKAGE = "com.classpackage"

SERVICE_PACKAGE = "com.classpackage"

info = jpype.JPackage(MODEL_PACKAGE).Info()

jpype.java.lang.System.out.println("Hello 2!!!")

#the error happens in this line below. This class service is a singleton.
service = jpype.JClass("com.classpackage.Service")

jpype.java.lang.System.out.println("Hello 3!!!")
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Anyone knows a workaround to use singletons in java using jpype in python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Service = jpype.JPackage("com.classpackage").Service
```

instead. Then call

```
instance = Service.getInstance()
```

to get the singelton.

Comment: `instance = Service.getInstance()
    RuntimeError: No matching overloads found. at src/native/common/jp_method.cpp:121`

got this error. This is strange, it must to work, but isn't.

Comment: @EvertonPreda make sure your version of JPype is at least 0.5.5. Get the latest version from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JPype1/